# autosave function in Ajax mode

Tags: ajax, xpages

I would realize a custom control for every XPages with a Notes Document Datasouces that have autosave funcionality (like google mail)

So that the event-handler is with "no validation"...

My question is...how execute this handler in Ajax Mode..so that the user don't refresh the current page?

Have someone any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the good old CSJS *executeOnServer* method for this. The method can be found here: http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

To disable the validation you have to add the parameter *valmode=0* to the partial refresh. This disables validators AND converters.

This is how the event handler should look like:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="autoSaveEvent" id="autoSaveDoc" submit="false">
   <xp:this.action>
      <xp:saveDocument />
   </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

The event handler can now be called from CSJS with this code:

```
executeOnServer('autoSaveDoc',null,{ 'valmode': 0 })
```

Comment: IMO disabled converters may lead to invalid data in autosaved document. Does it work to you, Daniele?

Comment: If you change the *valmode* to 1 this should enable the convertes only.